# google analytics api user login always having to login

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to create a google analytics dashboard and i'm running into an issue of having to re-login after the access token expires. What i mean by re-login is that once I click the redirect link to go google oauth, I have to choose which account I want to login as. Instead, I want to be able to always log in as a certain user.

The login flow that I want is as follows:

a user logs into the main page of the dashboard with a user/pass combination (NOT their google account)
this login takes them to the main dashboard showing the analytics. So i need to store access tokens for individual users, but the access tokens have an expiration date. Can I do this with the refresh token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to store the access token, refresh token, and when the access token will expire. Here are the docs on using a refresh token to get a new access token:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh